Stripe test subscription is not being automatically charged
I have a test subscription in stripe which has the "collection_method" set to "charge_automatically". Using the test clock to simulate future payments, I see that at the start of a new billing cycle only draft invoices are being generated instead of being charged automatically. While creating a new subscription or changing the subscription from one product to another the automatic payment does work like expected.
The invoice page shows the message "This draft invoice was generated by a subscription, but automatic collection was turned off." Manually charging the customer also works without a problem.
In the events page on stripe I see this message:
"[user's email] has an upcoming invoice scheduled for automatic payment in 1,427 days"
I'm sure that it was working a few days ago and stripe did not confused because of its own test clocks.
Invoices were being charged automatically before
I checked if the collection_method were set to "charge_automatically". I tried creating new prices, new products and new subscriptions but there is no change. Stripe is not attempting to charge the customers automatically.

This is hard to try to troubleshoot without looking at how you're creating the Subscription, and what your code looks like. However, I would recommend that you look at https://docs.stripe.com/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?platform=web&ui=elements#create-subscription. When you're simulating the Subscription, https://docs.stripe.com/billing/testing/test-clocks/simulate-subscriptions, you'd want to ensure that you've set the default payment method on the customer as well. Also, I recommend starting fresh with new test clocks as I can confirm that it's working for me.

I didn't write any code because the error persists even when I use the Stripe dashboard to create the subscription. I tried creating a new test clock but just like before stripe created a draft invoice and logged an "invoice.upcoming" event. The upcoming invoice still has the "collection_method" as "charge_automatically".
The message with the event says: "[email] has an upcoming invoice scheduled for automatic payment in 30 days". Those 30 days have already passed in the simulation.

Is this subscription paused? pause_collection parameter: https://docs.stripe.com/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-pause_collection
